# MYSQL Multiple fields and vaiable in CASE SELECT Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, variables, case

I am trying to select multiple fields from a case statement. I know the below syntax is wrong, but it describes what I am trying to do. Drawing particular attention to the CASE statement and the @type variable. Am I on the right track and if Im not some helpful poiters in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
Select
(tasks.id) As 'id',
(tasks.Title) As 'title',
(Excursions.ExcursionsColour) As 'backgroundColor',
(Excursions.ExcursionsColour) As 'borderColor',
CONCAT('taskcomplete.php?ex=',Excursions.idExcursions,'&id=',tasks.id) AS 'url',
CASE 
WHEN Excursions.typeID = '1' THEN
    date_sub(Excursions.ExcursionsStart, INTERVAL $tasks.Day_Incursion_days DAY)) As 'start',
    date_sub(Excursions.ExcursionsStart, INTERVAL $tasks.Day_Incursion_days DAY)) As 'end';
    SET @type = 'tasks.Day_Incursion';
WHEN '2' THEN
    tasks.Overnight_Interstate,
    date_sub(Excursions.ExcursionsStart, INTERVAL $tasks.Overnight_Interstate_days DAY)) As 'start',
    date_sub(Excursions.ExcursionsStart, INTERVAL $tasks.Overnight_Interstate_days DAY)) As 'end';
    SET @type = 'tasks.Overnight_Interstate';
WHEN '3' THEN
    tasks.International,
    date_sub(Excursions.ExcursionsStart, INTERVAL $tasks.tasks.International_days DAY)) As 'start',
    date_sub(Excursions.ExcursionsStart, INTERVAL $tasks.tasks.International_days DAY)) As 'end';
    SET @type = 'tasks.International';
END CASE;
From
  tasks,
  Excursions
Where
  @type = 'Y' And
  tasks.Sub_Task_Title = '' And
  ExcursionsUser = '$_SESSION[user]'
```

Thank you all... so I need to:

- Split my case statements
- run a sub query to get my type of excursion and apply it to my WHERE clause
- Join my tables, thanks for pointing that out. I had forgotten

I will post an update shortly.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think that a syntactically incorrect SQL statement would describe what you want to do.  Sample data, desired results, and some explanation generally work much better than non-working code.

Comment: Sorry Gordon, If I had the right syntax I wouldn't need to post a question;-) I thought this would be in preference to a lengthy text description.

Comment: You appear to have no correlation connecting your two tables, which is unlikely - there should be (at least one) columns in the two tables that are equal to each other.  You're also **wide** open to SQL Injection - use [parameterized queries](http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/812837) or suffer the consequences.  Most of your statement doesn't seem to require the `CASE` - the date math is the same in each branch (just use one variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You canot return multiple fields from a single case statement. You need to repeat the case with the same condition, once for each field.

Also the SET inside tha case is wrong.

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
Select * from 
(
select
CASE Excursions.typeID 
WHEN '1' THEN
    tasks.Day_Incursion
WHEN '2' THEN
    tasks.Overnight_Interstate
WHEN '2' THEN
    tasks.International
end as type
from 
...
)
where type = 'Y'
;
```

Comment: So in effect, I would need three CASE statements...OK. Can you set the variable by a case?

Comment: You can, but there's more wrong with your statement than this answer would suggest.

Comment: Clockwork-Muse is right. I really do not understand the where @type='Y', when you do not set 'Y' anywhere.

Comment: I think you can put another sql over the first one, and include the type as a field. I wll answer again.

Comment: This is appropriate for a comment, but not for an answer.